# Run code when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, load

This has *not* been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978740/javascript-how-to-detect-if-document-has-loaded-ie-7-firefox-3) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270431/check-from-bookmarklet-whether-page-is-loaded). These questions are poorly worded, and the answers are all along the lines of "use DOMReady".

I want to ensure that code is run only if the page has finished loading. I cannot alter the HTML file itself, but if I could, I would do something that amounts to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>window.loaded=false;</script>
  </head>
  <body onload="window.loaded=true;">
    <!-- ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in my code:

```
if (window.loaded) { run(); }
else { document.addEventListener("load", run); }
```

And that would achieve exactly what I want. Unfortunately, I cannot modify the HTML, which means that I am looking for a way to determine whether the document has **loaded** (*not* if the DOM is ready) from JS code only.

I have looked around quite a bit, but so far, all I have found revolves around DOMReady. Has no-one really ever looked for this?

Comment: In summary `DOMReady` isn't anywhere in the HTML5 spec, it's a term that means different things to the different people who implemented it before the HTML5 spec was fully developed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Dr.Molle points out, [`document.readyState`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#current-document-readiness) contains the property you're after:

> `document . readyState`
>
> Returns "loading" while the Document is loading, "interactive" once it is finished parsing but still loading sub-resources, and "complete" once it has loaded.
>
> The `readystatechange` event fires on the Document object when this value changes.

The order of event firing and readyState change is defined in the [end of parsing](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-end) section of the HTML5 spec. In summary:

1. The document `readyState` is set to `"interactive"` as soon as parsing is complete.
2. The `DOMContentReady` event is fired almost immediately (after it's determined which resources need to be loaded).
3. Those resources are loaded.
4. The document `readyState` is set to "complete" and the `load` event is fired.

Comment: I've removed some incorrect information from my post. DOMContentLoaded is not the same as `readyState="complete"`, as described in the [post-parsing](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-end) section of the HTML5 spec

Comment: Indeed. So, I made this: https://gist.github.com/2792934. To summarise: `DOMContentLoaded` is runs when the DOM is loaded. `onload` runs after everything is loaded. `readyState` is set to `"complete"` just before that. Hence, you were both right, but I still have to wonder about all the different and ambiguous naming :)

Comment: `DOMReady` wasn't ever an official term, but before the HTML5 spec got to the state it's currently in people needed a term to refer to. Now I guess a lot of the confusion comes from people mixing the correct term with the old name

Answer (score 3):

the onload-event of a window fires when the DOM and all ressources(scripts,images,stylesheets, etc.) have finished loading:

```
window.onload=function()
{
  //run code 
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does. But that's not what I'm asking. If my code is run _after_ the `onload` event has fired, this fails.

Comment: document.readyState is another option: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.readyState . It returns "complete" when the document has been loaded.

Comment: **No it's _not_.** I have specifically asked for _not_ DOMReady. Quoting the doc you linked to: "alternative to DOMContentLoaded".

Comment: DOM and document are two different things